# Using `isTRUE()` on a symbol `T` based on a sys.call

Tags: r, logical-operators

is there a version of `isTRUE()` that would also work on a symbol `T`?

To be clear, I don't mean the actual shorthand for `TRUE` which is `T` but a value of the class `symbol`.

This comes from a function that has saved its information in a `sys.call()` object - which saves a `TRUE` (i.e. a logical value) but when you input a `T` and then use sys.call() a `symbol` is saved rather than a `logical` value.

An example here:

```r
test_fun <- function(x, mc){
  out <- list()
  out$a <- rnorm(x)
  out$sys_call <- sys.call()
  out$match_call <- match.call()
  return(out)
}
```

Where then if I want to check the resulting object by accessing the `$call$mc` aspect, I don't identify the `T` as a logical value.

Here the main issue:

```r
main_example <- test_fun(2, mc = T)
main_example$sys_call$mc # showing T
main_example$match_call$mc # showing T

main_example$sys_call$mc == TRUE # resulting in FALSE
main_example$match_call$mc == TRUE # resulting in FALSE
isTRUE(main_example$sys_call$mc) # resulting in FALSE
isTRUE(main_example$match_call$mc) # resulting in FALSE

str(main_example$sys_call$mc) # showing that T is a symbol, not logical
str(main_example$match_call$mc) # showing that T is a symbol, not logical
```

I'm well aware that I should never use `T` but rather `TRUE` but how do I deal with a user inputting `T` in my package and always checking whether it's true?

Just using `as.logical()` throws an error:

```
cannot coerce type 'symbol' to vector of type 'logical'
```

Something like this would work, but it's a bit tedious... There must be a better way to do this :)

```r
is.symbol(main_example$match_call$mc) && main_example$match_call$mc == as.symbol("T")
```

Thanks!

Some more fun comparing `sys.call` and `match.call`:

```r
# here a small but unsatisfying advantage of match.call v sys.call
test_fun(2, T)$sys_call$mc
test_fun(2, T)$match_call$mc
# unsatisfying because it still does not recognise it as TRUE but just as symbol T
# but it's better than sys.call
is.logical(test_fun(2, T)$sys_call$mc)
is.logical(test_fun(2, T)$match_call$mc)

test_fun(2, mc = T)$sys_call$mc
test_fun(2, mc = T)$match_call$mc
# both fail to identify logical
is.logical(test_fun(2, mc = T)$sys_call$mc)
is.logical(test_fun(2, mc = T)$match_call$mc)

# here the advantage of match.call v sys.call
test_fun(2, TRUE)$sys_call$mc
test_fun(2, TRUE)$match_call$mc

# here the advantage of match.call v sys.call
is.logical(test_fun(2, TRUE)$sys_call$mc) 
is.logical(test_fun(2, TRUE)$match_call$mc)

test_fun(2, mc = TRUE)$sys_call$mc
test_fun(2, mc = TRUE)$match_call$mc

is.logical(test_fun(2, mc = TRUE)$sys_call$mc)
is.logical(test_fun(2, mc = TRUE)$match_call$mc)
```

Comment: You can always evaluate the symbol. ie `isTRUE(eval(test_fun(2, T)$call_2$mc))`

Comment: Right, so this would work on the `match.call()` but not the `sys.call()`, right?

Comment: `sys.call()` doesn't use the parameter names, but rather position. Thus you could do `isTRUE(eval(test_fun(2, T)$call_2[[3]]))`

Comment: Right, I understand!! Thanks a bunch Onyambu!!

Comment: @Onyambu : I think it might be more accurate to say that `sys.call` doesn't evaluate its parameter assignment. It does preserve name. In this case look at `dput(main_example$sys_call)`